# Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, tdd, jestjs, babel-jest

[image]

[Create-React-App] *Jest* and *Enzyme*(3.9.0) cant seem to find my `<Button/>` Element from `Auth.jx` container..
The application should render the Auth container `if(!isAuthernticated)` and the button should be disabled if no input is supplied.

I tried **ShallowWrapper::dive()** but i get a TypeError

`TypeError: SHallowWrapper::dive() can only be called on components`

**Auth.jsx**

```
    //...
    let errorMessage = null;
    let button=<Button id='Disabled' btnType="Success" disabled={false}>Disabled</Button>;
    let authRedirect = null;

    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
        authRedirect = <Redirect to={this.props.authRedirectPath}/>
    }
        if (this.state.controls.username.value && this.state.controls.password.value){

           button=<Button id='Login' btnType="Success">Login</Button>
          }
    return (
         <div>
        {authRedirect}
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                       {form}
                    {button}
                    </form>
        </div>
    )
}
 //...
```

**Auth.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {shallow} from 'enzyme';
import Auth from '../containers/Auth/Auth';
import Button from '../components/Button/button';
import Input from '../components/Input/input';

describe('<Auth/>',() =>{
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(()=>{
        wrapper=shallow(<Auth authRedirectPath='/' isAuthenticated={false}/>).dive()
    })

    //Test 1
    it('should render disabled button if no input has been specified ',()=>{
        expect(wrapper.find(Button).text()).toEqual('Disabled')
    });
})
```

Comment: Can you also post your `Auth.test.js` code?

Comment: posted @alvinLee

Comment: Do you use any HOC on the `Auth` component? For example `withRouter`?

Comment: i used redux's `connect` @zsgomori

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My comment above has explored that you use Redux's `connect` HOC on the component. That's why you can't access the desired component since that's a level deeper within the tree.

I'd suggest reading my article on [Medium](https://medium.com/c-hive/test-hocs-wrapped-component-with-jest-and-enzyme-e9155f80a217) in which you can find some details about the actual problem and also the appropriate solution.

---

**EDIT**

If you're still experiencing the same issue, I'd suggest the following:

Let's suppose that your `Auth` component is something like this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class Auth extends Component {
   // Something happens here.
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToprops)(Auth);
```

Notice that I used the `export` keyword in both cases. That being said, you can test the proper component without any connection to Redux and it also reduces the generated tree.

Pay attention to import the named export class within the test file:

```
...
import { Auth } from './Auth';
...
```

Comment: This works ! but the component should accept props like `isAuthenticated` which should render the Auth component if TRUE

Comment: That's still pretty easy. You should pass a mocked function to the wrapped component with the same prop name. Shall I edit my answer above so that present the solution?

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you should be calling `dive()` on the `wrapper` in your test. Instead, you should shallow render your `wrapper` *and then* call `dive()` or `render()` on the found `Button` to test for its text.

So, first:

```
wrapper = shallow(<Auth authRedirectPath='/' isAuthenticated={false} />)
```

Then, when you want to `find(Button)` and test for its text when rendered, you would do either of the following:

```
expect(wrapper.find(Button).dive().text()).toEqual('Disabled')

// OR

expect(wrapper.find(Button).render().text()).toEqual('Disabled')
```

**To demonstrate this, I've re-created a skeleton of your code here at this [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/z377q83p8m).** You can see, specifically in `Auth.test.js` how I have modified your original test with my code lines above. If you click on "Tests" in the bottom toolbar, you'll see that the test passes.

If you go into `Auth.jsx` and you change the `username` and `password` values - thereby affecting the `Button` text - then the test will fail.

Comment: This is the more practical response